# Allow multiple accounts in the Stack Exchange app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I have a feeling this has been asked before, but I'm not finding it. It would be nice to have the ability to switch between multiple accounts in the Stack Exchange iOS app, as Google allows in all of their websites. I have a couple of secondary accounts where I ask private questions that I don’t want associated to my main Stack Overflow account.

Comment: Generally you should have one se account. If you have more, ask for merging them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature should not be implemented, because it would make vote fraud and other cheating with multiple accounts easier.

In cases of secondary account being used for private questions this feature is also dangerous. When it's easy to swap accounts, one may get confused and reply from a wrong account, thus breaking all the secrecy.

You can use a separate devoted browser for each account. E.g. :

- primary account uses se client
- secondary 1st uses Firefox
- secondary 2nd uses Opera

Comment: Okay, I understand that. If [1-Password](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220983/add-1password-support-to-the-ios-app) were implemented into the app, this would be much less of an issue anyway.

Comment: @aliteralmind: never heard of that, thanks for the link.